# Showing submenu with jQuery in Joomla

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

I try to show a submenu after hovering over a menu item with jQuery (in Joomla!)

The HTML which is generated is:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav menu mainmenu">
    <li class="item-101"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php" >Home</a></li>  
    <li class="item-102 current active deeper parent"><a href="/sherpa_migrate
    /index.php/therapie" >Therapie</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-104"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php/therapie
        /kosten-en-vergoedingen" >Kosten en vergoedingen</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li class="item-103"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php/wie-ben-ik" >Wie  
    ben ik?</a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS I use:

```
nav ul ul {
padding-left: 5px;
margin-left: 0;
display: none;
}
```

The jQuery I have tried:

```
$('nav li.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow')
    }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp('slow')
});
```

But this won't show the submenu. I have tried to use an Alert, just to see if the mouseenter works and this just work fine.

Here is the JSFiddle I have created: https://jsfiddle.net/ujjvLzq9/

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: What's with the `stop()`? It appears to work fine without. https://jsfiddle.net/ujjvLzq9/1/ unless I misunderstand what you're after.

Comment: Removing the stop() does the job in jsfiddle. It is stil not working in Joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying different solutions I used Firebug console. It turned out that there was a JavaScript / Mootools / jQuery conflict. I changed my jQuery-script to:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery('.nav li.parent').mouseenter(function() {    
    jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast')
    }).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast')
});

});
```

Changing the $ to jQuery fixed the problem. nav and .nav did not make any different.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the dot on nav class in jquery event. Try work fine for me

```js
$('.nav li.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow')
    }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp('slow')
});
```

```css
nav ul ul {
padding-left: 5px;
margin-left: 0;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav menu mainmenu">
    <li class="item-101"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php" >Home</a></li>  
    <li class="item-102 current active deeper parent"><a href="/sherpa_migrate
    /index.php/therapie" >Therapie</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-104"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php/therapie
        /kosten-en-vergoedingen" >Kosten en vergoedingen</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li class="item-103"><a href="/sherpa_migrate/index.php/wie-ben-ik" >Wie  
    ben ik?</a></li></ul>
</nav>
```